# Same REST endpoint returning different Error Response Objects

Tags: json, rest, design-patterns, spring-boot, response

My Client app is a consumer of REST Endpoint producing JSON Responses which can return error responses having different structures for different scenarios;

**Error 1**

```
{ 
    "errorCode" : "XXXX"
    "errorMessage" : "Validation Failed"
}//Note the lack of higher order key here; it's flat
```

**Error 2**

```
{
  "apiError" : {
    "errorCode" : "XXXX"
    "errorMessage" : "Validation Failed"
  }
}//Note "apiError" is an object
```

**Error 3**

```
{
  "apiError" : [{
    "errorCode" : "XXXX"
    "errorMessage" : "Validation Failed"
  }]
}//Note "apiError" is a Collection
```

As we see above few of the error responses have same key but with different return types;

"errorCode" are embedded within the different keys and are also not globally appearing at same level with JSON Response.

I'm a little clueless as how to approach this scenario? Is there any design pattern or any work around it?

Some guidance is appreciated.

Comment: for the same request payload?

Comment: @Amit Kumar Ghosh - yes... Request Structure is same for all cases....

Comment: @Divs Are you using `RestTemplate` to consume these resources?

Comment: You are actually making it more difficult for your client since they will have to key off of `errorCode` shown in Error1 and `apiError` shown in the other Error types.  What you need is a single key which returns an array of objects of type `apiError`

Comment: My Application is Client application... it's the consumer, not the producer.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'standard' way to deal with this, but usually what you should do in this scenario is read the documentation of the API.

A good API probably uses the same json format for every type of error, but if they don't, they should at least document it. A good API probably also uses different media-types for each type of error (so you can inspect Content-Type to figure out how to parse the error message).

Maybe the API documents when each type of error is emitted. But if none of those guide you to a better way to deal with these types of errors in a general way, you might simply have to look at the response body and decide on how to parse it based on what was given to you.

Answer (score -1):

When designing a restful API, you need to use http status codes. There is relevant information on this [link.](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)

Sample responses are as follows.

Success Scenario(One or Multiple scenarios);

```
{
    "errors": null,
    "results": [{
        "key": "value"
    }]
}
```

Error Scenario;

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "code": "ERR-500",
        "message": "Error text"
    }],
    "results": null
}
```

Multiple Error Scenario;

```
{
    "errors": [{
        "code": "ERR-500",
        "message": "Error text"
    },{
        "code": "ERR-403",
        "message": "Error2 text"
    }],
    "results": null
}
```

Comment: The question mentions my application is consumer not producer.